# Symfony2 - doctrine:mapping:convert yml

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I wat to update my Entity from database.
I put to console:

```
 php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/Acme/CrudBundle/Resources/config/doctrine --from-database
```

This command generates Entities from 2 databases !
In `config/parameters.yml` I have everything ok.

What I should change ?
I need generate Entity just from database which I have in parameters.yml

Tkanks

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Comment: I know this.. But my import is from another database which I have in app/config/parameters.yml